# How to prevent ASP.net WP from terminating on error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nservicebus, cqrs, neventstore

I have some code in my ASP.net MVC project which asynchronously dispatches a message. Under certain circumstances that code can fail and cause an unhanded exception. I don't have direct access to the code which is throwing the exception or the code which is generating the thread so I'm unable to catch and handle the error there. I have tried catching at the Application_Error level in the Global.asax but that function is only thrown for page errors and not for background errors. I also tried catching in an HTTP module by implementing OnUnhandledException but I could find no way to catch the exception and prevent the worker process from existing in there.

Is there a way to prevent these errors from being so deadly? I understand they are serious errors and should be dealt with but I would rather they not terminate the worker process for other users on other pages.

**More specifics:**

The message dispatcher is EventStore and I believe the issue I had in this case was that it attempted to deserialize a message which implemented ICommand from a previous version of NServiceBus.  After updating to the latest beta it seems deserialization failed. Unfortunately I stupidly deleted the commit which was causing the error so I can't fully duplicate the issue.

The best way I've found so far to simulate the error is to do

```
   public virtual ActionResult Error()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(blowup);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
    private void blowup()
    {
        throw new Exception("snap");
    }
```

You'll notice the snap exception is thrown and properly processed without causing issues. However if you wait then the fact we didn't observer the exception property of the Task will eventually kill the entire application.

Tested against Cassini but similar behaviour seen on IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any unhandled exception causes the process to abort. This problem has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Hook up the unobservedtaskexception event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) to catch all exceptions (and send you and email).

I consider it to be best-practice to hook this event plus the Application_Error event plus the Thread.UnhandledException event.

Comment: That's a good note but my use of task was just a quick way to show that background thread exceptions were not being caught.

Comment: My suggestion will handle _all_ unhandled exceptions (if you also subscripe to the UnhandledException event).

Comment: Ah okay, great. I can now happily intercept and log the exceptions but it still brings down the worker process.  I found the key was to set the exception as observed http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bondib/archive/2011/02/08/crashes-task-parallel-library-tpl-and-the-unobservedtaskexception.aspx

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 1.1 had a backstop for all unhandled exceptions. It would quietly catch them and proceed on its merry way.

In .NET 2.0, Microsoft changed this to the behavior you now see: any completely unhandled exception will bring down the process, but you can handle some of those asynchronous exceptions through the "Handler Soup" of the Application_Error method, Thread.UnhandledException event, and in .NET 4.0, the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException.

Microsoft provides a config value in order to restore the .NET 1.1 behavior, which can be really critical in a web application where one errant exception could recycle the entire process, trashing valuable cache items in the process.

In the `<runtime>` section:

```
<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
```

The Microsoft article [Exceptions in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx) explains all this in greater detail.

Comment: That is not a good solution. Simply ignoring these errors isn't going to help anybody. There was a reason the functionality was changed in 2.0

Comment: Of course you should still log, triage, and fix. The question was how to prevent them from terminating the webapp.